# Error when assigning formula from VBA

Tags: vba

I am having 1004 error code in VBA when trying to assign the formulas to the cell with :

```
=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(C4,FIND(" ",C4)-1)),C4,LEFT(C4,FIND(" ",C4)-1))
```

my VBA code :

```
Range("U4:U" & lrow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(C4,FIND('" & "',C4)-
1)),C4,LEFT(C4,FIND('" & "',C4)-1))"
```

This gives error 1004. How do I fix this?

Comment: The reason actually is that you use `'` _apostrophe_ which is a _prefix character_. You use it upfront to indicate that the characters entered in a cell after it are _text_. The correct way to escape _space_ is as indicated by Vincent.

Answer (score 4):

You did not escape the " correctly and the space is missing. Try:

```
Range("U4:U" & lrow).Formula = "=IF(ISERROR(LEFT(C4,FIND("" "",C4)- 1)),C4,LEFT(C4,FIND("" "",C4)-1))"
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also shorten this to just:

```
Range("U4:U" & lrow).Formula = "=IFERROR(LEFT(C4,FIND("" "",C4)-1),C4)"
```

If you're using Excel 2007 or later.